# How java nio ServerSocketChannel accept works?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, nio, nonblocking

I can't get how NIO works under the hood. Here is a sample code:

```
// Create the server socket channel
ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
// nonblocking I/O
server.configureBlocking(false);
// host-port 8000
server.socket().bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(host,8000));

// Create the selector
Selector selector = Selector.open();
// Recording server to selector (type OP_ACCEPT)
server.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

while (true) {
      selector.select(); // blocking operation
      Iterator it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey selKey = (SelectionKey) it.next();

        // THE MOST INTRIGUING PART HERE!!!
        if (selKey.isAcceptable()) {
          ServerSocketChannel ssChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) selKey.channel();
          SocketChannel sc = ssChannel.accept();
        }
        it.remove();
     }
}
```

Here I have a couple of questions:

1. selKey.channel() return a ServerSocketChannel is it exactly the same channel we created in the beggining with ServerSocketChannel.open()? If not, then what is it?
2. More important question: in most other tutorials selKey.channel(); step is skipped and they simply use SocketChannel client = server.accept(); For example here: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/09/04/nio.html?page=2 and here: http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/10922_3837316_2/Non-Blocking-IO-Made-Possible-in-Java.htm So, how does server.accept() knows about current key we process?
3. In http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/10922_3837316_2/Non-Blocking-IO-Made-Possible-in-Java.htm they even suggest to accept channel in new thread. I guess it is possible that the following situation may occur.

   ```
   key1 someClient1 acceptable
   key2 someClient2 not acceptable
   key3 someClient3 acceptable

   startThread1
   startThread3

   scheduler decides to give time to thread3 instead of thread1

   thread3 -> socket.accept() <- actually accepts client1
   thread1 -> socket.accept() <- actually accepts client3
   ```

So, could you please explain how selector works in pair with ServerSocketChannel and accept method? Because I don't understand in which order #accept accepts clients and how this order related to selectedKeys.

4. Can I simply do the following:

   ```
   int availableClients = 0;
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       SelectionKey selKey = (SelectionKey) it.next();

       if (selKey.isAcceptable()) {
           ++availableClients;
       }
       it.remove();
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < availableClients; ++i) {
          SocketChannel sc = server.accept();
          doSomething(sc);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> selKey.channel() return a ServerSocketChannel is it exactly the same channel we created in the beginning with ServerSocketChannel.open()?

Yes.

> More important question: in most other tutorials selKey.channel(); step is skipped and they simply use SocketChannel client = server.accept(); For example here: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/09/04/nio.html?page=2 and here: http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/10922_3837316_2/Non-Blocking-IO-Made-Possible-in-Java.htm So, how does server.accept() knows about current key we process?

It doesn't. They're assuming that there is only one `ServerSocketChannel`. Your way is better: it's more general.

> In http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/10922_3837316_2/Non-Blocking-IO-Made-Possible-in-Java.htm they even suggest to accept channel in new thread.

I have no idea why. It's a non-blocking call. It will return immediately. The suggestion is pointless. Ignore it. It's a very poor quality tutorial from six years ago, but there were better ones in existence thirteen years ago. Try the Oracle tutorial. The author of this one doesn't seem to understand the point of non-blocking mode at all. The suggestion to use a separate thread for every event is completely and utterly ludicrous. He also doesn't understand how to use OP_WRITE. He makes a false assertion about `cancel()`. I could go on. It's doubtful that he has ever executed this code: he certainly didn't investigate its behaviour in any way. How to write a non-scalable NIO server. Quite a feat.

> I guess it is possible that the following situation may occur.

I don't even seen why you would be accepting in two threads at the same time, let alone how it could possibly matter to either thread which client it accepts. This is a difficulty invented where none exists.

> So, could you please explain how selector works in pair with ServerSocketChannel and accept method? Because I don't understand in which order #accept accepts clients and how this order related to selectedKeys.

The `accept()` method returns the next socket in the backlog queue, and OP_ACCEPT fires whenever the backlog queue is non-empty. It's perfectly simple, no mystery. The order doesn't 'relate to selected keys' at all. The selected key is that of the `ServerSocketChannel`.

EDIT: It appears you have a major misunderstanding. Consider:

1. You create and register a `ServerSocketChannel` for `OP_ACCEPT`.
2. Two clients connect simultaneously.
3. There is now exactly one `SelectionKey` in existence, and therefore exactly one in the selected-keys set: that of the `ServerSocketChannel`.
4. You then process your `isAcceptable()` case on that key; accept one or both connections; register those channels for `OP_READ.`
5. There are now three selection keys in existence, and none in the selected-key set, because you cleared it.
6. Both the clients send some data.
7. Now you have two selection keys ready to read in the selected-keys set.

OK?

> Can I simply do the following:

Certainly, but why? There is no advantage to be had by making something complicated out of something simple. Do it the first way.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, it's almost what I wanted to hear, but before I accept it as an answer I want to ask you to describe the following sentence in more details: "The accept() method returns the next socket in the backlog queue, and OP__ACCEPT fires whenever the backlog queue is non-empty." My last statement about "++availableClients" was just because I don't understand what is correlation between acceptable key and accept(). It looks like we could process one key, but accept another client which is puzzling for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct. You process the `ServerSocketChannel` key, and accept a newly created `SocketChannel` connected to a new client. The correlation is that when OP__ACCEPT fires, `accept()` won't return `null`.

Comment: Well, I mean if there is key1 for client1 and key2 for client2 and selectedKeys returns [key1,key2] then serverChannel.accept() may first create new channel for client2. And then, when we process key2 it will create new channel for client1. So, I think that the order is in fact random(at least for non blocking stuff), am I wrong?

Comment: What keys? What clients? You don't have either yet. There aren't *any* keys for clients until you (i) accept the connections and then (ii) register the new socket channels. Clients are accepted in the order they were put in the backlog queue, which depends on the order of completing the TCP handshake. The concept of 'clients out of order' doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, I mean 
SelectionKey selKey = (SelectionKey) it.next();
if (selKey.isAcceptable()) { server.accept() };

So, we have some keys here and doing accept. You say that clients are accepted in the order they were put in the backlog queue in the order of handshake completion. Is it the same order which is provided by selectedKeys().iterator()(only OP_ACCEPT)? Or it may be different?

Comment: Sigh. Again? *That's the key of the `ServerSocketChannel.`* Proven by the typecast `(ServerSocketChannel)key.channel()`. You asked about that yourself, so you should already know that. Surely? It's not a client key. It *can't* be a client key yet. See my previous comment for why. What you're supposing does not make sense.

Comment: Could you please recommend a good article about that? Before your last comment I didn't think that there are two types of keys (server and client), thanks for a hint!

Comment: OMG. There ***aren't***  two types of keys, and I didn't say otherwise, anywhere. I said 'client key' *referring to something that doesn't exist.* There is *one* type of key: `SelectionKey.` There are two types of *channels.* `ServerSocketChannel` and `SocketChannel.` I don't think any of this is sinking in. You have a ***serious*** misunderstanding somewhere, but I can't put my finger on it.