# How to make the accept() function non-blocking?

Tags: java, networking, java-threads

My server is listening to 2 ports ,and it should execute separate functions on each port simultaneously.

my problem is ,that the server blocks until the client of the first port is connected first.
For example: if a second client tried to connect to the 2nd port before a client connects to the 1st port ,it won't let it connect.

I created 2 classes that extends to thread class,so they should wait to any client in parallel instead of blocking what's after them.
But it doesn't seem to work as i'm expecting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("server is running.");
        int clientNumber = 0;
        ServerSocket listenerTrans = new ServerSocket(9899);
        ServerSocket listenerDeter = new ServerSocket(9898);
        try {
            while (true) {


                new Deteriment(listenerDeter.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
                new Transpose(listenerTrans.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
            }

        } finally {
            listenerTrans.close();
            listenerDeter.close();
        }
    }
```

Deteriment and Transpose are my classes that extend to thread class.

I want that the listenerDeter.accept() not to block the listenerTrans.accept(), i want that both of the thread's accept() happen in parallel.
Also why isn't it happening in parallel in my code?

Comment: I have solved it by opening a socket to the listenerDeter and closing it again if i wanted to use the listenerTrans,but isnt there a better solution to this?!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use a `ServerSocketChannel` and a `Selector`.  The `Selector` allows your application to multiplex I/O on multiple channels using a single thread.  It can be used in clocking or non-blocking mode

Here is an example (borrowed from [How java nio ServerSocketChannel accept works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441151/how-java-nio-serversocketchannel-accept-works) and adapted for your use-case):

```
// Create the 2 server socket channels
ServerSocketChannel server1 = ServerSocketChannel.open();
ServerSocketChannel server2 = ServerSocketChannel.open();
// Configure channels for nonblocking I/O
server1.configureBlocking(false);
server2.configureBlocking(false);
// Bind channels' IP and port
server1.socket().bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(host, 9899));
server2.socket().bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(host, 9898));
// Create the selector
Selector selector = Selector.open();
// Register channels to selector (type OP_ACCEPT)
SelectionKey key1 = server1.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
SelectionKey key2 = server2.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

while (true) {
    selector.select(); // blocks until one or more of the registered channels 
                       // has actionable I/O
    Iterator it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey selKey = (SelectionKey) it.next();
        if (selKey.isAcceptable()) {
            ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) selKey.channel();
            SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
            if (selKey.equals(key1)) {
                new Deteriment(sc.socket() ...).start();
            } else {
                new Transpose(sc.socket(), ...).start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Caveats: 1: not tested, 2: could be more elegant, 3: possible resource leaks, 4: you really should be using a thread pool / executor rather than firing off new threads by hand)

Comment: isn't there a way to do it by  ServerSocket and accept() , not by nio serversocketChannel ?

Comment: Nope.  Not without creating a thread for each `ServerSocket`.  The `ServerSocket.accept()` call is a blocking call.  Period.   (What is you problem with using NIO?)

Comment: could you show me an example of creating a thread for each ```ServerSocker``` ?

Comment: 1) See @Fourth's answer.  2) There must be hundreds of tutorials out on the web that cover that!

Comment: i already have tried his answer ,it didn't work..i created the threadpool outside while loop ,then inside i called the 2 serversockets with threads..it didn't block in the beginning but as i increased the number of clients ,it started to block. (also the performance was a bit slow)

Comment: Then see my 2).  I'm not keen on writing code to show you how to do this the "wrong" way. Also, you didn't answer my question(!)

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all if you like it to be async you need to use separate thread for every ServerSocket what u declare. Why? Becouse by the conception java.net was blocking not scalable way of dealing with net thinks. If you like it to be non-blocking more scalable but less abstrac (I mean you will allocate buffers ^*^) you should look for java nio instead. 
**EDIT: **
I little modyf your code it should make job done but its improvable i mean its not the most elegent version ^*^

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("server is running.");
    final int[] clientNumber = {0};
    ServerSocket listenerTrans = new ServerSocket(9899);
    ServerSocket listenerDeter = new ServerSocket(9898);
    try {
        ExecutorService ex = Executors
            .newFixedThreadPool(2);
            ex.execute(
                () -> {
                    try {
                        Socket s = listenerDeter.accept();
                        new Deteriment(s, clientNumber[0]++).start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            );
            ex.execute(
                () -> {
                    try {
                        Socket s = listenerDeter.accept();
                        new Transpose(s, clientNumber[0]++).start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            );
    } finally {
        //listenerTrans.close();
        //listenerDeter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,but i want to solve it using serverSocket and accept() ,isn't there a way ?

Comment: Like i said you should use separate thread for every serverSocket if you like to but i am not sure u probable get exception like 'multyserversocket on one host' but in this case i can be wrong. If that is possible the only way is by separate threads

Comment: I edit my post u can change executors for normal threads if u like to

Comment: without while loop ,it is only excuted twice(non blocked) .. when i added while loop , it starts to block after a number of clients

Comment: Using separate threads does not constitute non-blocking. Please correct all the spelling mistakes in your post.

Comment: its starts blocking becouse accept() wait for host to connect thats all if u get client it create the socket instace. Im not sure what u realy wont. If u just like it to go async them my answer is good but if u like just non blocking them u need to look at java nio as I said i hope it helps

Comment: @user207421 thanks for it that was my mistake ^_^ its realy late in my country