# How does a Java web server, like Jetty, continually listen for new connections without terminating in main?

Tags: java, jetty

I was trying to understand the "best practices" for preventing a program from terminating in main, using a Jetty web server as an example.

Where can I find the code in Jetty that loops constantly waiting for a connection? Is Jetty essentially using a `while(true)` loop somewhere? Or is there a more effective method to preventing the web server from terminating in main?

Comment: `Jetty essentially using a while(true) loop somewhere?` Pretty much.

Comment: Jetty uses NIO.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441151/how-java-nio-serversocketchannel-accept-works for answer

Comment: Ah that's perfect @JoakimErdfelt can you post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty uses Java NIO to handle all Networking (listening, accepting, reading, writing, closing, etc).

See other answer on details about NIO accept.

[How java nio ServerSocketChannel accept works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441151/how-java-nio-serversocketchannel-accept-works)